# Add feature to open privileges in a new tab with middle mouse click

Tags: feature-request, privileges

In the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page when I middle mouse click on any of the privileges it doesn't open in a new tab. Even when I right click on them there isn't an "Open in new tab" option

Please add these features.

Comment: Who came up with the luminous idea to not use `<a>` tags for links?

Comment: They're not `<a>` or `<button>` or anything that might indicate a link, so my poor vimium is completely at a loss and I can't tell what anything grants (without resorting to barbarian mobile pointing devices). :(

Comment: @robw That is funny.  `<div class="privilege-row-table" data-href="/help/privileges/trusted-user">` followed by an `onclick` handler below.  They reimplemented the `<A>` tag!  `StackExchange.ready(function () { $(".privilege-table-row").on("click", function (elem) { document.location.href = $(elem.delegateTarget).attr("data-href"); }); });`

Comment: You know, <a> has some stupid behavior that can't be fixed with CSS, so let's use JS instead.

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I could open a new tab with the middle mouse!

Comment: I'd call that an outright [[tag:bug]] in the markup!

Comment: This also happens in the tag score located in the user profile.

Comment: OK, it's working now. somebody tag this as `status-completed`